# Meteor method called from React components responce and error callbacks are always undefined?

Tags: reactjs, meteor

And on the server side I have  method:

```
Meteor.methods({
    'group.new'({ name, desc }) {
        if (!Meteor.userId()) {
            throw new Meteor.Error('You need to be logged in to comment');
        }
        Groups.insert({
            name,
            desc,
            createdBy: Meteor.userId(),
            created: new Date(),
        });
    },
});
```

And I'm calling this from a React component on the front-end:

```
        Meteor.call(
            'group.new',
            {
                name: this.state.name,
                desc: this.state.desc,
            },
            function(err, res) {
                console.log(err);
                console.log(res);
            },
        );
```

Why are both err and res always undefined?

Comment: Is the insert working?

Comment: Yes thats working fine.

Comment: Then that's why. You don't get an error obj because you're not hitting the error condition. You are not getting a success after the insert because you're not explicitly returning anything! Maybe put a ```return true``` after the insert. You'll then be able to receive it as a ```res``` in the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't seem to be returning anything back to the client from the server. That is why, when the insert succeeds, your `resp` object in the client is still undefined. The error object, however should work. Maybe it's just that you've not hit the error condition.

This will work:

**server.js**

```
Meteor.methods({
    'group.new'({ name, desc }) {
        if (!Meteor.userId()) {
            throw new Meteor.Error('You need to be logged in to comment');
        }

        // if insert succeeds, it will return the _id of the doc.
        var result_id = Groups.insert({
            name,
            desc,
            createdBy: Meteor.userId(),
            created: new Date(),
        });

         return result_id; // send the id back to the client
    },
});
```

Now if you `console.log(res)` on  the client, you should be able to view the  _id of the inserted doc that was sent back from the server.